# Devise edit form in modal, not populating fields unless it's rendered from the normal edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to have Devise users be able to edit from a  modal.  The problem is, when the modal loads, it doesn't populate the forms with any information.  But if I open the modal from `/users/edit` the form does populate.  Anyone know how to go about this?

`_edit.html.haml`

```
    .row
      .small-2.large-4.columns 
      .small-4.large-4.columns 
        %h2
          Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}
        = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { :multipart => true, method: :put }) do |f|
          = devise_error_messages!
          %div
            = f.label :email
            %br/
            = f.text_field :email
          %div
            = f.label :company_name
            %br/
            = f.text_field :company_name
          %div
            = f.label :branding
            %br/
            = f.file_field :branding
          %div= f.submit "Update"
        %h3 Cancel my account
        %p
          Unhappy? #{button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete}
        = link_to "Back", :back
      .small-6.large-4.columns
```

It's rendered from my `application/layout` like this:

```
#editProfile.reveal-modal{"data-reveal" => ""}
    = render "devise/registrations/edit"
    %a.close-reveal-modal ×
```